# Error : ORA-14155: missing PARTITION, PARTITIONS, SUBPARTITION, or SUBPARTITIONS keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I m trying to rename columns dynamically in Oracle.
I have a table whose column is named on month names, every month I need to refresh the data and change column names accordingly.

```
DECLARE
  v_cur_month_name VARCHAR2(100);
  i                INT := 0;
  vsql             VARCHAR2(250);
BEGIN
  FOR my_tab IN (WITH month_counter AS
                    (SELECT column_name, rownum AS cnt
                    FROM all_tab_columns
                    WHERE lower(owner) = 'ppl'
                    AND lower(table_name) = 'test')
                   SELECT column_name AS MONTH, cnt FROM month_counter WHERE rownum <= 12) LOOP

    v_cur_month_name := to_char(to_date(extract(MONTH FROM to_date(to_char(add_months(SYSDATE, i), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')), 'MM'), 'MONTH');

    vsql := 'alter table ppl.test rename column' || my_tab.month || 'TO' || v_cur_month_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vsql;
    i := i + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

For this: i am getting error as:

> ORA-14155: missing PARTITION, PARTITIONS, SUBPARTITION, or SUBPARTITIONS keyword
>
> ORA-06512: at line 20

Comment: Very poor design when you name columns according to month.

Comment: could you just name the fields current_month, month_minus_1, month_minus_2 etc. so you don't need to rename the fields each month?

Comment: @MatthewHart, such design is equally poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add spaces to get correct syntax:

```
vsql := 'alter table ppl.test rename column' || my_tab.month || 'TO' || v_cur_month_name;
=>
vsql := 'alter table ppl.test rename column ' || my_tab.month || ' TO ' || v_cur_month_name;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=684cc47069ea494e232b7f11ba0f4bd3)**

---

Anyway dynamic column rename indicates poor design.